# CSS question about Id selector problems?

Tags: css, css-selectors

How can i get the `ba` selector to work when I use it as an id selector instead of a class selector in the following code?

This will not work with the `ba` as the id attribute.

```
#abc textarea#ba {
   height: 400px; 
   width: 660px;
}
```

This will work with the `ba` as the class attribute.

```
#abc textarea.ba {
   height: 400px; 
   width: 660px;
}
```

Comment: you need to show your html too.

Answer (score 4):

I can't see why your example wouldn't work.

Are you 100% sure you have a textarea with the ID `ba` inside an element with the ID `abc`? Remember, `name` attributes don't count. Maybe you have a duplicate `id` in one of the elements? Also, remember that you can assign multiple classes, but *not* multiple IDs like `id='abc def'`.

Edit: This works fine for me:

```
<style type="text/css">
#abc textarea#ba {
   height: 400px; 
   width: 660px;
   background-color: lightyellow;
}

</style>

<div id="abc">
  <textarea id="ba">
    I'm 400  wide, 660 tall and light yellow!
  </textarea>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

The whole point of id's is that they're unique (identifiers) so you should never *need* to select in this way and should just use

```
#ba {
   height: 400px; 
   width: 660px;
}
```

If you have multiple #ba's then you're not doing it right.

> 'id = name [CS] This attribute assigns
>   a name to an element. This name must
>   be unique in a document.'

Source: http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2

Comment: That's not *necessarily* so, though. If I only want to affect #ba when it is in #abc (if it might not be), it's a legit use.

Comment: @DN Ah fair point. I was looking at it from a different angle.